# Proving or Disproving Lipschitz Continuity

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ be Lipschitz-continuous and bounded function.

Is the function 
$$
g: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, \; (x,y)  \mapsto  f(x)y.
$$
also Lipschitz-continuous?

My proof attempt would be 
$$
|| g(x,y) - g(x^\prime, y^\prime ) || \leq | f(x)y - f(x^\prime)y | +
| f(x^\prime)y - f(x^\prime)y^\prime | \leq |y| C | x - y | + C| y - y^\prime | ). 
$$

However, this is not sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Counterexample: Let $f(x)=\sin x,$ and set $g(x,y)=f(x)y.$ Consider the points $p_n=(0,n^2),q_n=(1/n,n^2).$ Then $|p_n-q_n|\to 0,$ but

$$|g(p_n)-g(q_n)| =|0-\sin(1/n)n^2|\sim n \to \infty.$$